# Jira filter to list ticket created between a time period of day

Tags: jira, jql

How to create a JQL filter to list all tickets created between 8 AM to 4 PM irrespective of created day and date?

I know startOfDay() deal with only for current day. For example , below will list all ticket created of 'myproject' between 8 AM and 4 PM  of current day (as per timezone set in my user profile)

```
  created > startOfDay("+8h") and created < startOfDay("+16h") and projecy='myproject'
```

My requirement is list a ticket created **any day** (not only current day) in my work shift 8 AM to 4 PM.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can not be fulfilled with simple JQL queries. You could query the database directly with some SQL or you can use some scripting with a plugin (check out [this post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/eazybi-time-of-day/qaq-p/378683) for example).

Other possibilities are to use the JIRA API to receive the ticket data and then filter the tickets which were created in the desired time frame.

Another possibility to at least get the relevant tickets from the current week with a JQL query could be to create a filter like this: `created > startOfWeek(7h) AND created <= startOfWeek(17h) OR created > startOfWeek(31h) AND created <= startOfWeek(41h)...` ([Source](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-can-I-create-a-filter-with-time-range/qaq-p/60951))